# Why is the value of `i` not changing to what I'm changing it to inside the loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I want to change the value  of `i` in the loop to `high` once `x = True` but I don't know why every time the loop starts again, value of `i` changes to `i++` not to `high+1`
here's the code :

```py
    def max_min(self, data, high, low):
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        x = False
        c = 0
        for i in range(c, len(data)):
            print(f"i = {i}")
            if i == low:
                if high > low:
                    list1.append(data[i])
                    list2 = data[low + 1:high]
                    x = True #once this condition is true
                    print(f"list2 = {list2}")
                else:
                    list2 = data[low + 1:]
                    print(f"list2 = {list2}")
            else:
                list1.append(data[i])
            print(f"list1 = {list1}")
        if x == True:
            c = high
        return list1, list2
```

FOR MORE CLARITY : HERE'S the output with every iteration, Assume `high = 6,for i in range(7)`:

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
```

whereas ideally it should be

```
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3 
# x = True, high = 6
i = 6 #high = 6
```

Comment: `for i in range(7)` is `i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` fixed. No matter how many times you change the `i` value within the loop,in the next iteration it'll follow the sequence `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. try with while-loop. Also, your `if x == True:` seems to be outside of for-loop by indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would offer three suggestions:

1. Change `i` rather than `c` to `high`.
2. Change it inside the loop, not outside.
3. Realise that it's not going to work anyway since the `for in` will revert it to the next item in sequence regardless of what you do with the loop control variable :-)

That last point you will see in action if you attempt to run:

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    i = 9999
```

It will print `0..9` despite the changes to `i` inside the loop. If you want a loop which will allow your changes to hold, `for in` is not what you're looking for. Try a `while` loop instead, something like:

```py
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    # Weave your magic here, including changing i to
    # whatever you want.

    i += 1
# Carry on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to actively influence the loop, you need a `while` loop. If you manually set `i` at some point in the `for` loop, it will be automatically reset at the beginning of the next iteration to the next value in line. E.g.:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == 3:
        i = 100
    print(i)
```

In a `while` loop however, you can change the iterating variable / condition:

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    if i == 3:
        i = 100
    print(i)
```

Translated to your case, I guess this is what you end up with:

```py
def max_min(data, high, low):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    x = False
    i = 0
    while i < len(data):
        print(f"i = {i}")
        if i == low:
            if high > low:
                list1.append(data[i])
                list2 = data[low + 1:high]
                x = True  # once this condition is true
                print(f"list2 = {list2}")
            else:
                list2 = data[low + 1:]
                print(f"list2 = {list2}")
        else:
            list1.append(data[i])
        print(f"list1 = {list1}")

        if x is True:
            i = high
            x = False
        else:
            i += 1

    return list1, list2


max_min([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 6, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range(7):` is `i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` fixed. No matter how many times you change the i value within the loop,in the next iteration it'll follow the sequence `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`.
Also, your if `x == True:` seems to be outside of for-loop by indentation.

Try while-loop

```
i = c
while i<len(data):
    ....
    if x == True:
         i = high
    else:
         i += 1
```